# Copying parts of a string several times in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, copy

I have a source code from a website where textmessages start with "< h2 >" and end with "< /h2 >". In my app, I read the source code and make it into a string. Now I want to read only the messages, and have tried with this:

```
returned = get.getInternetData("http://blablabla.com");
int start = returned.indexOf("<h2>") + 4;
int end = returned.indexOf("</h2>");
String message = returned.substring(start, end);
```

The problem is that I only get the very first message! My idea was to use a scanner object and do something like

```
while (scan.hasNext("<h2>")) {
        }
```

But there are no get-methods from the scanner. How can read all the messages from the source code?

Comment: You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to easily read html file that you got from Internet

Comment: What about replacing `<h2>` and `</h2>` with an empty string? Something like `message  = returned.replaceAll( "</?h2>", "");`

Comment: How will that help? I still want to read the messages in between, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this:

```
while (returned.indexOf("<h2>", lastIndex)!=-1) {
   .... 
   do your thing
   ...
   increment lastIndex 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) you can do this:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://blablabla.com").get();
 Elements h2Tag = doc.select("h2");
 ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(Element mess: h2Tag){
     messages.add(mess.text());
 }
```